# Incrementing pointers in C arrays

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to understand the below program. Specifically, the definition of  `cur_name` and the incrementing of the pointer for `cur_age` in the printf statement.

`*(cur_age + i)` must be indexing each of the integers in the array but I would have expected this to point to successive addresses in memory and not the next integer given ints are 4 bytes? i.e. why not i+4

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ages[] = {23, 43, 12, 89};
    char *names[] = {"Anne", "Kay", "Joe", "Pete"};
    int count  = sizeof(ages) / sizeof(int);
    int *cur_age = ages;
    char **cur_name = names;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%s is %d years old.\n", *(cur_name + i), *(cur_age + i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is simply how the pointer arithmetics is defined in C. Incrementing the pointer always considered to be incrementation in units, where one unit is the `sizeof()` of type being pointed to.

Side note - while int's are **commonly** 4 bytes in size, this is not set in stone. They might as well be smaller (2 bytes) or longer (really not limit).

Comment: So when incrementing a pointer it takes into account the type, great! As for the character array, I understand this is a pointer to an array of pointers but why the **.

Comment: @CatsLoveJazz, not really. It is an array of pointers (not a pointer to such array). Every element of this array is a pointer to `char*`, with size of `char*` size (for example, 8 bytes). Arrays can `decay` to the pointers (in fact, they do it almost always), so when you say `char** cur_name = names` `names` is *decayed* into pointer to pointer to char.

Comment: I will have to digest that, thanks. I was referring to the `cur_name` variable.